# Restsharp JSON response search

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I need to search the following JSON response.  I have no control over how the JSON is returned to me or how it is nested.  I am using Restsharp by default, but I am open to whatever method helps me accomplish the task.

```
{
    "response": [
        {
            "id": 1008,
            "brandId": 74,
            "collectionId": 32,
            "productTypeId": 1,
            "nominalCodeStock": "1200",
            "nominalCodePurchases": "5002",
            "nominalCodeSales": "4000",
            "seasonIds": [
            ],
            "identity": {
                "sku": "SKU0001",
                "isbn": "0684843285",
                "ean": "ISNB09712345",
                "upc": "5778400001",
                "barcode": "738737638"
            },
            "productGroupId": 0,
            "featured": false,
            "stock": {
                "stockTracked": true,
                "weight": {
                    "magnitude": 0.7
                },
                "dimensions": {
                    "length": 2,
                    "height": 12,
                    "width": 5,
                    "volume": 120
                }
            },
            "financialDetails": {
                "taxCode": {
                    "id": 7,
                    "code": "T20"
                }
            },
            "salesChannels": [
                {
                    "salesChannelName": "Brightpearl",
                    "productName": "Product B",
                    "productCondition": "new",
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "categoryCode": "276"
                        },
                        {
                            "categoryCode": "295"
                        }
                    ],
                    "description": {
                        "languageCode": "en",
                        "text": "Some description",
                        "format": "HTML_FRAGMENT"
                    },
                    "shortDescription": {
                        "languageCode": "en",
                        "text": "Some short description",
                        "format": "HTML_FRAGMENT"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "composition": {
                "bundle": false
            },
            "variations": [
                {
                    "optionId": 1,
                    "optionName": "Colour",
                    "optionValueId": 1,
                    "optionValue": "Black"
                },
                {
                    "optionId": 3,
                    "optionName": "Colour",
                    "optionValueId": 9,
                    "optionValue": "Black"
                }
            ],
            "warehouses": {
                "2": {
                    "defaultLocationId": 5,
                    "reorderLevel": 1,
                    "reorderQuantity": 0
                },
                "3": {
                    "defaultLocationId": 0,
                    "reorderLevel": 1,
                    "reorderQuantity": 1
                }
            },
            "createdOn": "2015-01-08T17:57:18.000Z",
            "updatedOn": "2015-04-01T13:17:58.000Z",
            "reporting": {
                "categoryId": 353,
                "subcategoryId": 369,
                "seasonId": 2
            },
            "primarySupplierId": 202,
            "status": "LIVE",
            "salesPopupMessage": "Offer the extended warranty",
            "version": 1192098806000
        }
    ]
}
```

Specifically I need to retrieve the categoryCode values.  I'm lost on this one.  Any direction is much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried specifically related to *searching this response*, what isn't working? For us to help, please update your post to include what you've tried.

Comment: I've tried to create a dynamic object and use either XPath or Linq, but I don't seem to be able to construct the search properly.  Essentially, I don't know how to dig down that far in the response.

Comment: @zaggler, I finally got it:  JObject o = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
                                        IList<JToken> CategoryCodes = o.SelectToken("response[0].salesChannels[0].categories").ToList();

                                        foreach (JToken jt in CategoryCodes)
                                        {
                                            Debug.WriteLine(jt["categoryCode"].ToString());
                                        }